# How can I enforce filename and folder name convention in typescript eslint?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I am using `eslint` for `typescript` convention. And I checked this rule `https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md` which only works for code.

I am looking for a rule which can enforce filename to be `camelCase` and folder name to be `snake_case`. How can I set this rule in typescript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eslint doesn't implement by default the file name check, see [this github issue from 2015](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2412).

Some plugins do like [eslint-plugin-unicorn](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/docs/rules/filename-case.md) or [eslint-plugin-filenames](https://github.com/selaux/eslint-plugin-filenames).

---

Because Tslint is now deprecated, they created the project [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md), which is handling file naming casing, you could check it out :)

Comment: Does it solve file and folder separately? I see it treat file and folder the same.

Comment: Look like [eslint-plugin-unicorn doesn't](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/issues/686) as much as in [eslint-plugin-filenames](https://github.com/selaux/eslint-plugin-filenames/issues/23)

Comment: I've found [this very new plugin](https://github.com/christopherbradleybanks/eslint-plugin-folders) one contributor, from 9 days ago. Idk if it's worth it to include it into your project considering

Comment: @Orelsanpls the link for typescript-eslint is not very helpful here. The rule only applies to identifiers within files (functions, classes, variables …), not the files themselves.

The link to the github issue pretty clearly states that checking file names is out-of-scope.

Answer (score 11):

The eslint plugin [eslint-plugin-check-file](https://github.com/DukeLuo/eslint-plugin-check-file) allows you to enforce a consistent naming pattern for the filename and folder.

Apply the `camelCase` style to filename:

```js
{
   "rules":{
      "check-file/filename-naming-convention":[
         "error",
         {
            "*.{js,ts}":"CAMEL_CASE"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Apply the `snake_case` style to folder name:

```js
{
   "rules":{
      "check-file/folder-naming-convention":[
         "error",
         {
            "src/**/":"SNAKE_CASE"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Check out this [link](https://github.com/DukeLuo/eslint-plugin-check-file) for more information about `eslint-plugin-check-file`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a few more resources after the fact - I found for filenames, that [eslint-plugin-filename-rules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-filename-rules) worked well.

For enforcing eslint on folders, [eslint-plugin-folders](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-folders) worked for me for directories with files in it. The documentation says only `.js` and `.jsx` files but `.ts` and `.tsx` files worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

My [eslint-plugin-project-structure](https://github.com/Igorkowalski94/eslint-plugin-project-structure) package is perfect for this.
It gives you full control over how you want your project structure to look like.

Here is the list of current features:

✅ Validation of project structure (Any files/folders outside the structure will be considered an error).
✅ Validation of folder and file names.
✅ Name case validation.
✅ Name regex validation.
✅ File extension validation (Support for all extensions).
✅ Inheriting the parent's name (The child inherits the name of the folder in which it is located).
✅ Folder recursion (You can nest a given folder structure recursively).
✅ Forcing a nested/flat structure for a given folder.

example:

1. Only files that meet `snake_case` can be in the `src` folder (Add allowed extensions).
2. Only folders that meet `camelCase` can be in the `src` folder (you can add rules for folder children).

You can also use [folder recursion](https://github.com/Igorkowalski94/eslint-plugin-project-structure#folder-recursion) to add the rules above for each nested folder

```
{
    "structure": {
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "src",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "/^${{snake_case}}$/",
                        "children": [
                            // ... rules for folder children.
                            // If you only care about the folder name, leave it as [].
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "/^${{camelCase}}$/",
                        "extension": "*"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "extension": "*"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here you will find a detailed description of the API.
https://github.com/Igorkowalski94/eslint-plugin-project-structure#api