# Enforce file naming convention with typescript-eslint

Tags: typescript, tslint, typescript-eslint

I want to automatically enforce file naming conventions for my typescript + react codebase.

e.g. all `.ts` filenames have to be `camelCase`
all `.tsx` filenames have to be `PascalCase`

[Orelsanpls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62465164) has referenced `typescript-eslint` doing that, however I can only find the [naming-conventions](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md) rules for variables, classes, members etc.

TSLint contained [file-name-casing](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/file-name-casing/) rules, which is exactly what I'm looking for in `typescript-eslint`.

Am I missing something about naming-conventions in `typescript-eslint`?

Comment: I believe you can achieve it by using ts compiler api. Here you can find nice article https://davidgomes.com/using-the-typescript-api-to-find-issues-in-your-code/?utm_source=typescript-weekly.com&utm_campaign=typescript_weekly_160&utm_medium=email

In case there is no such rule in typescript-eslint

Comment: https://github.com/selaux/eslint-plugin-filenames

Comment: @captain-yossarian, thank you, very interesting!

Comment: @ritaj, thank you! I've seen that already when searching, the package is not maintained anymore though and I'm looking for sth to rely on for some time!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I enforce filename and folder name convention in typescript eslint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62464592/how-can-i-enforce-filename-and-folder-name-convention-in-typescript-eslint)

Answer (score 1):

The only supported plugin I could find today doing so is [eslint-plugin-unicorn](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn) you can see the reference to the rule that can help you here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/docs/rules/filename-case.md

You might want to only enable this rule as the plugin comes with many other opinionated rules that you might or might not agree with.