# Is there a way to lint the unit test file's directory name in `jest` when commit unit test file?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, lint

Suppose there is a project that uses `jest`, which requires unit test files to be placed in the `__tests__` folder.

I want to find a way to lint the unit test file's directory name. What I expect is that an error will occur when someone commit their unit test files to the wrong directory like `__test__` or `_tests_`.

Is there any existed lint tool can do this? Can someone know how to do it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do this directly in ESLint, however, by [following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62464592/how-can-i-enforce-filename-and-folder-name-convention-in-typescript-eslint) you could use an external plugin.  You would then just need to run ESLint with the proper file mask (**/*.spec.ts) to perform the linting you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @steven-scott context sharing. When I checked the plugins mentioned in the answer, I found that both [`eslint-plugin-folders`](https://github.com/christopherbradleybanks/eslint-plugin-folders), [`eslint-plugin-filename-rules`](https://github.com/dolsem/eslint-plugin-filename-rules), and [`eslint-plugin-filenames`](https://github.com/selaux/eslint-plugin-filenames) could not satisfy my requirement. So I create a new eslint plugin [`eslint-plugin-check-file`](https://github.com/DukeLuo/eslint-plugin-check-file) to do it.

Using the plugin `eslint-plugin-check-file`, just configure the rule `check-file/folder-match-with-fex` as follows can lint the unit test file's folder name as `__tests__/`:

```js
{
   "rules":{
      "check-file/folder-match-with-fex":[
         "error",
         {
            "*.test.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}":"**/__tests__/"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Check out this [link](https://github.com/DukeLuo/eslint-plugin-check-file) for more information about `eslint-plugin-check-file`